# Android : How to get all friend a of person using App FB SDK 2.4

Tags: android, sdk

I create a app facebook and use create button login on app (android).
I want when a person open app and login then i can get all friend of they.But i try ways but do not (return Null).Please for me a suggest.
Thank all!
This is my code:

```
private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mCallback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(getActivity(), Arrays.asList("user_friend","user_location", "user_birthday", "user_likes","user_photo"));
                new GraphRequest(
                        AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                        "/me/taggable_friends",
                        null,
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.getJSONObject() + "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                ).executeAsync();
        }
    @Override
    public void onCancel() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.4/user/friends

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/me/friends",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

**Permissions**

A user access token with user_friends permission is required to view the current person's friends.
This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.
If a friend of the person declines the user_friends permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.

**Modifiers**

You can append another person's id to the edge in order to determine whether that person is friends with the root node user:

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{user-id-a}/friends/{user-id-b}",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

If user-a is friends with user-b in the above request, the response will contain the User object for user-b. If they are not friends, it will return an empty dataset.

Comment: Thank to Arsal Imam.I think use Access token third-party ,eg: IOS and then use it get list friend by: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=installed&access_token=access_token&format=json